# Python получить несколько подстрок из строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Имеется строка

```
Free space "974.62MB" in the Storage[/home/doom] has dropped  below the recommended threshold "5GB", it is recommended to free up space in the storage as soon as possible
```

Нужно получить из этой строки данные в кавычках и скобках. То есть: 974.62MB, /home/doom, 5GB.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Используя регулярные выражения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения.

Пример:

```
import re

string = 'Free space "974.62MB" in the Storage[/home/doom] has dropped below the recommended threshold "5GB", it is recommended to free up space in the storage as soon as possible'

# Извлечение данных в кавычках
quoted_data = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', string)
# Извлечение данных в скобках
bracketed_data = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', string)

print("Quoted data:", quoted_data)
print("Bracketed data:", bracketed_data)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично! Благодарю!

Comment: Можно выбрать одним выражением все, например `(?<="|\[)[^"\]\[]*?(?="|\])`. [Демо](https://regex101.com/r/zO9kUj/1)